# Can I use jenkins to trigger Build on another jenkins

Tags: ios, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I want to know if it is possible to run a build on jenkins through another jenkins.

I have two separate jenkins running on two different computers how can I possibly run a build job on one of them from the other ?

If I am building an iphone application and I try to build and deploy it through jenkins, I know I need a mac to develop iphone apps but do I need a jenkins to be running on a mac to build and deploy those applications or can it be running on any computer with any os ?

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it you don't need another jenkins instance but a [jenkins slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds). This is used to build jenkins jobs on other platforms.

I have slave that run on WinXP, Win7 32bit, Win7 64bit and Ubuntu. However my jenkins instance runs on Ubuntu (not the same as the slave). This way jobs can be created with specific labels that will correspond to labels on the slaves.

Example:

- job 1, label: ios
- job 2, label: winxp
- jenkins master: label ubuntu
- jenkins slave1: label ios
- jenkins slave2: label winxp

This way job 1 will only run on slave 1 and job 2 will only run on slave2 and you don't need to do anything about it.